# header checkbox not working first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

hey everyone i have two view

```
1- Index
2- Edit
```

i have a grid its header have one checkbox i want to click checkbox all rows checkbox is checkbox. in my header checkbox its not working first time when i click uncheck then check its work fine. i dont know why and what is the problem in my code please help

here is my index view its have Script

```
         function Check_Uncheck() {
            $('#SelectAll').click(function () {
                if (this.checked) {
                    $('.checkbox:enabled').each(function () {
                        this.checked = true;
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $('.checkbox:enabled').each(function () {
                        this.checked = false;
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

and here is my Edit its have checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="SelectAll" onclick="Check_Uncheck();" tabindex="3" />
```

Comment: can u add [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select and unselect all checkboxes of the gridview row, then you can do something like below:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SelectAll(obj) {
        var valid = false;
        var chkselectcount = 0;
        var gridview = document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>');
        for (var i = 0; i < gridview.getElementsByTagName("input").length; i++) {
            var node = gridview.getElementsByTagName("input")[i];
            if (node != null && node.type == "checkbox") {
                node.checked = obj;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Gridview aspx:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"
                    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"></asp:GridView>
```

And onButton click

```
     Select : 
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkdelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Text="All" OnClientClick="SelectAll(true); return false"></asp:LinkButton>
                    | 
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkundelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Text="None" OnClientClick="SelectAll(false); return false"></asp:LinkButton>
```